# Python - Create matrix from a string

Tags: python, string, interface, matrix, tkinter

I have to create a matrix (or an array) from a string file like this:

```
>>>print Qval
[1*10**4,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1*10**3,0], [0,0,0,1]
>>>print type(Qval)
<type 'str'>
```

I have to get the matrix this way, because in my Tkinter GUI I have to input the value like this (part of the interface: field label= default value):

Q-Matrix= [1*10**4,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1*10**3,0],[0,0,0,1]

I get the Qval string from my interface like this:

```
Qval=vars[13].get()
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1e4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1e3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]')
([10000.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1000.0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in function eval like that:

```
a ="[1*10**4,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1*10**3,0], [0,0,0,1]"
mat = eval(a)
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` is safer.